# Display srt file as text in QuickLook

Tags: quicklook, launch-services

On an old 10.12 MBP, srt files are displaying as text in Quicklook.
But on another laptop under 10.15, they're not: I have the VLC file icon and can"t get a way to display the file content as text in QL.
On both computers, all the SRT files are set to default open with VLC.

Tried to trace preview with `qlmanage -p file.srt`, which only gives this for the new one:

```
2020-11-27 15:04:28.046 qlmanage[11094:574062] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x6a03, name = 'com.apple.coredrag'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2020-11-27 15:04:28.158 qlmanage[11094:574062] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xb01f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
```

But says it uses TextMate's QL plugin on the old one. TextMate is installed on both computers.

So I tried `mdls file.srt` on the old one:

```
...
kMDItemContentType             = "org.videolan.srt"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "org.videolan.srt",
    "public.item",
    "public.text",
    "org.videolan.srt",
    "public.data",
    "public.content",
    "public.plain-text"
)
...
kMDItemKind                    = "Subrip Subtitle File"
...
```

while on the new one:

```
...
kMDItemContentType                     = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge81g6xy"
kMDItemContentTypeTree                 = (
    "public.item",
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge81g6xy",
    "public.data"
)
...
kMDItemKind                            = "Subrip Subtitle File"
```

I tried to find how to add this `public.plain-text` entry on the new one, and tried

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '<dict><key>LSHandlerContentType</key><string>org.videolan.srt</string><key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key><string>org.videolan.vlc</string><key>LSHandlerIgnoreCreator</key><true/></dict>'

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

But nothing works.

Kind of trivia but very annoying not to know how to change this.
Any clue?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe worth trying: select an .srt file in Finder. Get Info > Open With > Text Edit. Select "Change All". Log out of your Mac. Log back in, and repeat the process, except use VLC instead of Text Edit. Might help re-write the setting for QuickLook. Just a guess, as I said, but it's what I would try if I was having this problem.

Comment: @TJLuoma thanks for the suggestion – didn't think of logging in/out. No changes though :/